# Merging dataframes with different dimensions and related data

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with different size with related data to be merged in an efficient way:

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame({'kpi_1': [1,2,3,4]},
                         index=['dn1_app1_bar.com',
                                'dn1_app2_bar.com',
                                'dn2_app1_foo.com', 
                                'dn2_app2_foo.com'])


guard_df = pd.DataFrame({'kpi_2': [1,2],
                         'kpi_3': [10,20]},
                         index=['dn1_bar.com', 'dn2_foo.com'])
```

master_df:

```
                  kpi_1
dn1_app1_bar.com      1
dn1_app2_bar.com      2
dn2_app1_foo.com      3
dn2_app2_foo.com      4
```

guard_df:

```
             kpi_2  kpi_3
dn1_bar.com      1     10
dn2_foo.com      2     20
```

I want to get a dataframe with values from a `guard_df`'s row indexed with `<group>_<name>` "propagated' to all `master_df`'s rows matching
`<group>_.*_<name>`.

Expected result:

```
                  kpi_1  kpi_2  kpi_3
dn1_app1_bar.com      1    1.0   10.0
dn1_app2_bar.com      2    1.0   10.0
dn2_app1_foo.com      3    2.0   20.0
dn2_app2_foo.com      4    2.0   20.0
```

What I've managed so far is the following basic approach:

```
def eval_base_dn(dn):
    chunks = dn.split('_')
    return '_'.join((chunks[0], chunks[2]))

for dn in master_df.index:
    for col in guard_df.columns:
        master_df.loc[dn, col] = guard_df.loc[eval_base_dn(dn), col]
```

but I'm looking for some more performant way to "broadcast" the values and merge the dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use pandas 0.25+ is possible pass `array`, here `index` to `on` parameter of `merge` with left join:

```
master_df = master_df.merge(guard_df, 
                            left_on=master_df.index.str.replace('_.+_', '_'), 
                            right_index=True, 
                            how='left')
print (master_df)
                  kpi_1  kpi_2  kpi_3
dn1_app1_bar.com      1      1     10
dn1_app2_bar.com      2      1     10
dn2_app1_foo.com      3      2     20
dn2_app2_foo.com      4      2     20
```

Comment: Thanks, tested with pandas 0.24+ and it seems to work. Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: @attdona - I think it working nice for pandas 0.24+ too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> pd.merge(master_df.assign(guard_df_id=master_df.index.str.split("_").map(lambda x: "{0}_{1}".format(x[0], x[-1]))), guard_df, left_on="guard_df_id", right_index=True).drop(["guard_df_id"], axis=1)
                  kpi_1  kpi_2  kpi_3
dn1_app1_bar.com      1      1     10
dn1_app2_bar.com      2      1     10
dn2_app1_foo.com      3      2     20
dn2_app2_foo.com      4      2     20
```