# How to merge two dataframes with different length based on string contains

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with data augmentation in medical imaging. I have original 100 image names with their labels (0 and 1) in Pandas dataframe. I added new images and their name with some suffix.

My original images have names such as: Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4 and my augmented data have names such as: Image1_1, Image1_2, Image2_1, Image2_2, Image3_1, Image3_2, Image4_1, Image4_2 etc.

My Pandas DataFrame contains annotation with two columns: filename and label.

My another Pandas Dataframe contains only original filenames and augmented file names without labels.

```
filename = [f for f in os.listdir(path_to_dir_with_augmented_images)]
annotations = pd.read_csv("annotations.csv", names=["filename", "label"])

filenames = []
for file in filename:
    filenames.append(file)

data = pd.DataFrame(filenames, columns=["filename"]
```

My annotation files have 100 lengths and data file have above 1000.

I want to have output such as:

```
filename, label
Image1, 0
Image1aa1, 0
Image1aa2, 0
Image2, 1
Image2baa1, 1
Image2baasa2, 1
```

How to do it in Pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging dataframes with different dimensions and related data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867074/merging-dataframes-with-different-dimensions-and-related-data)

Comment: @Chris it's not solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

#create dummy data
data = pd.DataFrame([['Image1aa1'], ['Image1aa2'], ['Image2baa1'], ['Image2baasa2']], columns=['filename'])
annotations = pd.DataFrame([['Image1',1],['Image2',0]], columns=['filename','label'])

for name, l in zip(annotations.filename,annotations.label):
    temp = data[data['filename'].str.match(name)]
    temp['label'] = l
    annotations = annotations.append(temp)
```

Comment: I just edited my question. I don't have exactly augmented data with "_". I have augmented file names contains substring of original filename.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit your previous code, and it's still work!